# Can't get Date from String with p. m. format

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I try to get Date from String, but I get the Nil.
I will be grateful for any help

```
let stringDate = "2022-05-26 7:00:12 p. m."

let dateFormatWithPM = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = dateFormatWithPM
df.amSymbol = "a. m."
df.pmSymbol = "p. m."

let date = df.date(from: stringDate)
```

Comment: It was returning ```nil```. I copied the  ```p. m.``` part inside ```stringDate``` and put it as the  ```df.pmSymbol```. Then it started working. I don't know why it is working.

Answer (score 0):

HH should give you a 24 hour format which conflicts with the am/pm components.

Change your format to: `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"`

EDIT:

```
let stringDate = "2022-05-26 7:00:12 p.' 'm."

let dateFormatWithPM = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = dateFormatWithPM
df.amSymbol = "a.' 'm."
df.pmSymbol = "p.' 'm."
```

This snippet works because apparently the formatter is reading the space and tries to parse the m. as a separate component.